# How log the command output in the Robot framework log file after test execution?

Tags: robotframework

In Robot Framework log.html, I want to log the command output that I am executing from a python file . As shown in the attached screenshot of log.html, now I am not able to see the command output. Simple it prints or logs as PASS.

My Robot File:

```
*** Settings ***
Library         test


*** Test cases ***
check
    test
```

Python Keyword:

```
def test():
    cmd = ' net test" '
    output = os.popen(cmd).read()
    match1 = re.findall('.* (successfully).*',output)
    mat1 = ['successfully']
    if match1 == mat1:
        print "PASS::"
```

Can anyone guide me on this please?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want the output of the command to appear in  your log, there are three ways to do it: using the print statement, using the logging API, or using the built in log keyword. These methods are all documented in the [robot framework users guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html).

Of the three, the logging API is arguably the best choice.

#### Using print statements

You're already using this method. This is documented in the user guide, in a section named [Logging information](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#logging-information):

> ... methods can also send messages to log
>   files simply by writing to the standard output stream (stdout) or to
>   the standard error stream (stderr) ...

Example:

```
def test():
    cmd = ' net test" '
    output = os.popen(cmd).read()
    match1 = re.findall('.* (successfully).*',output)
    mat1 = ['successfully']
    if match1 == mat1:
        print "output: " + output
```

### Using the logging API

There is a public API for logging, also documented in the user guide
in a section named [Public API for logging](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#programmatic-logging-apis):

> Robot Framework has a Python based logging API for writing messages to
>   the log file and to the console. Test libraries can use this API like
>   logger.info('My message') instead of logging through the standard
>   output like print '*INFO* My message'. In addition to a programmatic
>   interface being a lot cleaner to use, this API has a benefit that the
>   log messages have accurate timestamps.

Example:

```
from robot.api import logger
def test():
    ...
    logger.info("output: " + output)
```

### Using the built-in Log keyword

Finally, you can also use the built-in [log](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Log) keyword. Using the built in keywords is documented in the user guide in a section titled [Using BuiltIn Library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-builtin-library).

> Test libraries implemented with Python can use Robot Framework's
>   internal modules, for example, to get information about the executed
>   tests and the settings that are used. This powerful mechanism to
>   communicate with the framework should be used with care, though,
>   because all Robot Framework's APIs are not meant to be used by
>   externally and they might change radically between different framework
>   versions.

Example:

```
from robot.libraries import BuiltIn
...
def test():
    ...
    BuiltIn().log("this is a debug message", "DEBUG")
```