# How to solve garbled characters starting with "\u0e" in the Robot Framework log

Tags: python, json, character-encoding, robotframework, python-2.x

My example code

```
POST_Create_Ticket
    ${userpass}=    Convert To Bytes    ${jirausername}:${jirapassword}
    ${userpass}=    Evaluate    base64.b64encode($userpass)    base64
    ${headers}=    create dictionary    Content-Type=application/json    Authorization=Basic ${userpass}   charset=utf-8
    ${issuetype}    Create Dictionary    name=Bug
    ${project}      Create Dictionary    key=XXX
    ${fields}       Create Dictionary    project=${project}  summary=ทดสอบ  description=Test Desc  issuetype=${issuetype}
    &{data}         Create Dictionary    fields=${fields}
    log to console   ${data}
    create session    jira    https://setthapong.atlassian.net    verify=True
    ${response}=    post request      jira    /rest/api/2/issue    headers=${headers}   data=${data}
    log    ${response.text}
    should be equal as integers    ${response.status_code}    201
```

I got log to console as below
look at summary it shows garbled characters in log

```
{"fields": {"project": {"key": "XXX"}, "summary": "\u0e17\u0e14\u0e2a\u0e2d\u0e1a", "description": "Test Desc", "issuetype": {"name": "Bug"}}}
```

The summary should be show ทดสอบ

[image]

I tried to solve it by change 'ASCII' to 'utf-8' but it's not work

```
if PY2:

def _unic(item):
    if isinstance(item, unicode):
        return item
    if isinstance(item, (bytes, bytearray)):
        try:
            return item.decode('utf-8')
        except UnicodeError:
            return u''.join(chr(b) if b < 128 else '\\x%x' % b
                            for b in bytearray(item))
    try:
        try:
            return unicode(item)
        except UnicodeError:
            return unic(str(item))
    except:
        return _unrepresentable_object(item)
else:

def _unic(item):
    if isinstance(item, str):
        return item
    if isinstance(item, (bytes, bytearray)):
        try:
            return item.decode('utf-8')
        except UnicodeError:
            return ''.join(chr(b) if b < 128 else '\\x%x' % b
                           for b in item)
    try:
        return str(item)
    except:
        return _unrepresentable_object(item)
```

Comment: That's what it does; the string is JSON-encoded. You should find that `print("\u0e17\u0e14\u0e2a\u0e2d\u0e1a")` produces the output `ทดสอบ`. (Why are you using Python 2 though?)

Comment: I'll try to find a better duplicate but the basic answer is "nothing is wrong, you just need to understand what you are looking at".

Comment: I would like the html Robot log shows correctly character.

Comment: Then you have to transform it to a string before logging it. You are apparently logging the whole `dict` and then Python applies its default formatting to that. Maybe see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33065809/how-log-the-command-output-in-the-robot-framework-log-file-after-test-execution

Comment: @tripleee Although `{u'fields': {u'project': {u'key': u'XXX'} ...` is not JSON.

Comment: Mmm true, slight terminological inaccuracy in my first comment.

Comment: I solved it by     log    ${data}[fields][summary] before post req